# Does Sql Server Express supports MSDTC

Tags: sql-server-2005, msdtc

I need MSDTC(Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator) in one of my application. I am not sure whether it is available on Sql Server Express editions.

I googled on MSDN and haven't got clear answer on this. It seems with googling that it is avaialble but not started when sql server is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, distributed transactions are supported on all editions of SQL Server.

Comment: It's fully supported and enabled in all editions of SQL Server.  If you have a document that shows otherwise, I'd love to see it.

Comment: We may not understand the same thing by enabled, but I had to enable remote access on my setup (win10 home + sql server express 2016) as illustrated is the link provided in my previous comment. Sure, this is not a document, just personal experience.

Comment: I had written before mrdenny comment: "Supported but maybe not fully enabled. See this [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30959127/1178314) answer if in need of enabling remote access by example." Sorry for the initially broken link. Now it is fixed.